# Avoid redundant code in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have table with Light Athletic's competitions results. Players earns points for first three places.
I need list with Names of athletics which their points.
I have this:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(many) as sum FROM
(
(SELECT NAME, count(*) * (SELECT points from "points for place" where place = 1)  as many
FROM RESULTS R1 WHERE
(SELECT count(*) FROM RESULTS R2 WHERE
    R1.result < R2.result
    AND R1.DISCIPLINE = R2.DISCIPLINE
    AND R1.CITY = R2.CITY) = 0
GROUP BY NAME)
UNION
(SELECT NAME, count(*) * (SELECT points from "points for place" where place = 2)  as many
FROM RESULTS R1 WHERE
(SELECT count(*) FROM RESULTS R2 WHERE
    R1.result < R2.result
    AND R1.DISCIPLINE = R2.DISCIPLINE
    AND R1.CITY = R2.CITY) = 1
GROUP BY NAME)
UNION
(SELECT NAME, count(*) * (SELECT points from "points for place" where place = 3)  as many
FROM RESULTS R1 WHERE
(SELECT count(*) FROM RESULTS R2 WHERE
    R1.result < R2.result
    AND R1.DISCIPLINE = R2.DISCIPLINE
    AND R1.CITY = R2.CITY) = 2
GROUP BY NAME)
)
GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY SUM;
```

I have three times almost the same redundant code. If this weren't depend from place, I could use View...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @JakubKuszneruk Have you tried using `IN`?

Comment: @njk
I tried sth like place in (1, 2, 3), but then I have 2 problems:
1. ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
2. how make place visible in line "AND R!.CITY = R2.CITY) = x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simplify this with:

```
select r.name, 
       sum(p.points) total_points
  from (select city, discipline, name, 
               row_number() over (partition by city, discipline order by result) place
         from results r) r
       inner join "points for place" p
               on p.place = r.place
 where p.place <= 3 
 group by r.name
 order by total_points desc;
```

* note: if there can be a tie, and you want both to count as that place, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

also the `where p.place <= 3` may be redundant given your test data as you only have 3 places scored...so you can omit that. i've left it in though.

but what i'm confused about is that in your original SQL and Erwins answer, you've both inverted the places. i.e the guy who ran longest was 1st?!

i.e in your fiddle you had:

```
-- RESULTS --
INSERT INTO results VALUES
('9.87', 'Doha', '100m', 'Justin GATLIN');
...
INSERT INTO results VALUES
('10.28', 'Doha', '100m', 'Jimmy VICAUT');
```

now  i read that as Justin WON in 9.87 seconds. yet you've both counted that as Jimmy's win.

if that is so, then the analytic should be

```
partition by city, discipline order by result desc
```

Comment: Yeah, your query with `dense_rank()` is obviously the better solution. Just didn't know what the query is about, when I started working on it. It was  .. hidden well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can radically simplify to:

```
SELECT name, sum(p.points) AS total_points
FROM  (
    SELECT r1.name
          ,sum((r1.result > r2.result)::int) + 1 AS place
    FROM   results r1
    LEFT   JOIN results r2 USING (discipline, city)
    GROUP  BY 1
    HAVING sum((r1.result > r2.result)::int) < 3
    ) r
JOIN   "points for place" p USING (place)
GROUP  BY r.name
ORDER  BY total_points;
```

This is tested with **PostgreSQL**.
Since the OP later declared Oracle, here is another version for **Oracle**:

```
SELECT name, SUM(p.points) AS total_points
FROM  (
   SELECT r1.name
         ,SUM(CASE WHEN r1.result > r2.result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1 AS place
   FROM   results r1
   LEFT   JOIN results r2 USING (discipline, city)
   GROUP  BY r1.name
   HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r1.result > r2.result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 3
) r
JOIN   "points for place" p USING (place)
GROUP  BY r.name
ORDER  BY total_points;
```

Should deliver the same result as the query in the question. Only much faster and simpler.
[->**sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c2d2/29) showing new query and original side by side.

Now that I know what this query is about: `dense_rank()` is obviously the better solution.

#### Major points

- For Postgres, `sum((r1.result < r2.result)::int)` counts the number of times where `r1.result` is lower than `r2.result`. `boolean` cast to `integer` yields 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.
  For Oracle this expression does the same:

  ```
   SUM(CASE WHEN r1.result < r2.result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ```
- I add `1` to that count and name it `place` to fetch `points` from the table `"points for place"` with it.

Comment: I can't solve this error:
   ,sum((r1.result < r2.result)::int) + 1 AS place
                    *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @JakubKuszneruk: I added a version for Oracle. If you had provided a test case (table definition + sample values) I could actually test it ...

Comment: I will be grateful if you could.
1) [creating_tables](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~jk320790/create_tables.sql)
2) [data](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~jk320790/init.sql)

Comment: @JakubKuszneruk: Your test case is too big for sqlfiddle. Can you work on this one to bring it down to a reasonable size for a quick test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/7057. And post the working fiddle, when you are done?

Comment: [there it is](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c2d2/6) you forgot about comma in 3. line, but something else is wrong too

Comment: @JakubKuszneruk: Thanks for the working fiddle. I used it to debug the query and updated my answer.

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e61a/2). Unfortunately I had bug (< signs should be replaced with >). Now our solutions returns better results, but your solution don't sum points from different competitions (I added Churandy MARTINA two  times).